# Is C++'s new operator reentrant (or async-safe)?

Tags: c++, reentrancy

The background is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090368) of mine. Put shortly, I *have to* `fork` in a multithreaded C++ program, so I'd like to figure out how much I can do when restricted to reentrant functions only, and one of the most essential things is dynamic memory.

So, `malloc` is [known to be non-reentrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941271). But what about C++'s `new`? I googled for that with not many relevant results (mostly due to the difficulty to hit the correct "new"), but there is at least one claim that [`new` **is** reentrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613077#4613231). There is also a [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036520) concerning the whole C++ standard library with no satisfying answer.

Edit: I guess the standard didn't say anything about this, so I'm mostly concerned about major implementations.

Comment: Which version of the standard are you working to?

Comment: I think you are confusing reentrancy with thread safety. A function can be thread-safe but not reentrant.

Comment: @interjay read the background question for why I insist on reentrancy, not just thread-safety.

Comment: I don't know who can say something definitive about malloc, if I was you I would higly suggest to read something from the standard about malloc, malloc doesn't even grant some memory to be really allocated, if you want "safe code" you probably want to avoid malloc because malloc it's not defined and it's implementation dependant so its behaviour is platform-specific .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looked at both the `gcc` [libsupc++](https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/tree/master/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++) and `clang` [libc++](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/src/) source, for replacing the standard-conforming C++ new/delete operators - to support native SIMD alignment requirements on platforms where it wasn't guaranteed by `malloc`.

They are basically wrappers for `malloc` and `free` with some EH logic, etc. I am not a language lawyer, but unless both have it wrong, I think it's safe to conclude: no, they are not reentrant.

Answer (score 3):

Standard **allows** `new` to be just a wrapper around `malloc`, so if `malloc` can be not reentrant, so can `new`.

Comment: While this is the case for almost all implementations, a minor nitpick is that the standard doesn't say `new` **must** use `malloc`. So it may or maynot hold true.

Comment: @AlokSave added emphasis on _allows_ ;)

Comment: @AlokSave in [section 16.4.6.9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/reentrancy) the C++ standard defines that "Except where explicitly specified in this document, it is implementation-defined which functions in the C++ standard library may be recursively reentered". That is part of the library part of the standard, but as long as the [basic part of the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.stc.dynamic.allocation) does not explicitly state something I would assume that new is not reentrant.

Answer (score 1):

Thread-safety and re-entrance are not *exactly* the same.

AFAIK, the C++ ISO standard does not guarantee thread-safety for `new` and `delete` operators. But `g++` implementation does provide thread-safetly (and it's one of the reasons it's slow).

Comment: The question is about reentrancy. :) Read the background question for why I insist on that.